# How to update plot without redraw figure

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I draw grid inside a circle, and when I pick any grid, I will add a rectangle object to circle. But when the grid number is large(over 40000) and there are many rectangles have been added, the plot figure time would be very long.

I think that is because every time I add rectangle I will redraw the figure. 
So I think if I can **just** update figure and not to redraw it, it will be much faster. But, unfortunately, I can not find any api to do it in matplotlib. Does anybody have any idea to solve this problem ?  Thank you !

Here's part of my code :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import numpy as np

def onclick(event):
    """add Rectangle when click any gird on circle"""
    try:
        rect = patches.Rectangle((int(event.mouseevent.xdata), int(event.mouseevent.ydata)), 1, 1, facecolor=(.7, .9, .9, .9), edgecolor=(.2, .1, .1,.5))
        ax.add_patch(rect)
        rect.set_clip_path(circ)
        # redraw can update the figure, but it would take long time
        fig.canvas.draw()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e.args)


r = 50  # radius
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
plt.grid(True)

circ = patches.Circle((0, 0), radius=r,
                      facecolor=(.5, .5, .5), edgecolor='black', picker=5)
ax.add_patch(circ)

# Fill half of circle with rectagles
for x in range(int(-r/2), int(r/2)):
    for y in range(int(-r/2), int(r/2)):
        if x + y < r * r:
            rect = patches.Rectangle((x, y), 1, 1, facecolor=(.7, .5, .5, .5), edgecolor=(.2, .1, .1, .5))
            ax.add_patch(rect)
            rect.set_clip_path(circ)

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onclick)

# Diable any ticks and labels
plt.tick_params(
    axis='both',
    left='off',
    bottom='off',
    labelleft='off',
    labelbottom='off'
)
plt.xlim([-r-1, r+1])
plt.ylim([-r-1, r+1])
plt.xticks(np.arange(-r-1, r+1))
plt.yticks(np.arange(-r-1, r+1))
plt.setp(ax.xaxis.get_gridlines(), clip_path=circ)
plt.setp(ax.yaxis.get_gridlines(), clip_path=circ)

plt.axes().set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

Comment: "Update" and "redraw" are the same things in this case. You may however try to *blit* the new rectangle onto the canvas. Before doing that I would first try to not add individual rectangles though, but instead work with a single `PolyCollection` with as many shapes as you need.

Comment: Thanks for your advise. I'll try to use PolyCollection to see if it works.